# Why is data target not finding the id of my modal?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

I have a program where the user can delete a line from a text file, however, before deleting, i would like for there to be a confirmation modal where the user can double check that he/she is deleting the correct line. However, my modals id does not seem to be linking with the data toggle of the button responsible for bringing up the modal?

Button to bring up modal:

```
<button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]">Delete</button>
```

To provide additional context; "@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[0]" is a part of the line within the text file, i am using this in order to be able to tell which line needs to be deleted.

Below is my modal, where i am using the same id value as the data toggle above:

```
<div class="modal" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[0]</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("DeleteCategoryLine", "Index", new { id = dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1] })'">Yes</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Is it even possible to use data toggle and id in the way i have above?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the id with the selected line of your text file? What if your text line has spaces? Give a static id-name and refer it in data-target since this popup is not dynamically generated as per my understanding. Your objective will be achieved inside modal body, which is to show what line is deleted

Comment: The problem with doing that is, i have an on click event that needs to happen when the modals 'yes' is pressed. The modal and both the button shown in the question above fall within a foreach loop, and without the modal having the id's stated above, the functionality will not work as intended. The user wont be able to delete the desired line.

Comment: Sorry, i dint see any note about loop. Anyways, you can use the index if you are using a loop, as the id instead of the line (can filter out the line by the index) . Also data-target should look like ``` data-target="#id" ``` you are missing "#"